# Dynamically parse yaml field to one of a finite set of structs in Go

Tags: parsing, go, yaml, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a `yaml` file, where one field could be represented by one of possible kinds of structs. To simplify the code and yaml files, let's say I have these yaml files:

```yaml
kind: "foo"
spec:
  fooVal: 4
```

```yaml
kind: "bar"
spec:
  barVal: 5
```

And these structs for parsing:

```golang
    type Spec struct {
        Kind string      `yaml:"kind"`
        Spec interface{} `yaml:"spec"`
    }
    type Foo struct {
        FooVal int `yaml:"fooVal"`
    }
    type Bar struct {
        BarVal int `yaml:"barVal"`
    }
```

I know that I can use `map[string]interface{}` as a type of `Spec` field. But the real example is more complex, and involves more possible struct types, not only `Foo` and `Bar`, this is why I don't like to parse `spec` into the field.

I've found a workaround for this: unmarshal the yaml into intermediate struct, then check `kind` field, and marshal `map[string]interface{}` field into yaml back, and unmarshal it into concrete type:

```golang
    var spec Spec
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &spec); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tmp, _ := yaml.Marshal(spec.Spec)
    if spec.Kind == "foo" {
        var foo Foo
        yaml.Unmarshal(tmp, &foo)
        fmt.Printf("foo value is %d\n", foo.FooVal)
    }
    if spec.Kind == "bar" {
        tmp, _ := yaml.Marshal(spec.Spec)
        var bar Bar
        yaml.Unmarshal(tmp, &bar)
        fmt.Printf("bar value is %d\n", bar.BarVal)
    }
```

But it requires additional step and consumes more memory (real yaml file could be bigger than in examples). Does some more elegant way exist to unmarshal yaml dynamically into a finite set of structs?

Update: I'm using `github.com/go-yaml/yaml v2.1.0` Yaml parser.

Comment: Which yaml package and version of the package are you using?

Comment: @mkopriva sorry, updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For use with `yaml.v2` you can do the following:

```golang
type yamlNode struct {
    unmarshal func(interface{}) error
}

func (n *yamlNode) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    n.unmarshal = unmarshal
    return nil
}

type Spec struct {
    Kind string      `yaml:"kind"`
    Spec interface{} `yaml:"-"`
}
```

```golang
func (s *Spec) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    type S Spec
    type T struct {
        S    `yaml:",inline"`
        Spec yamlNode `yaml:"spec"`
    }

    obj := &T{}
    if err := unmarshal(obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *s = Spec(obj.S)

    switch s.Kind {
    case "foo":
        s.Spec = new(Foo)
    case "bar":
        s.Spec = new(Bar)
    default:
        panic("kind unknown")
    }
    return obj.Spec.unmarshal(s.Spec)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ov0cOaedb-x

---

For use with `yaml.v3` you can do the following:

```golang
type Spec struct {
    Kind string      `yaml:"kind"`
    Spec interface{} `yaml:"-"`
}
```

```golang
func (s *Spec) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    type S Spec
    type T struct {
        *S   `yaml:",inline"`
        Spec yaml.Node `yaml:"spec"`
    }

    obj := &T{S: (*S)(s)}
    if err := n.Decode(obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch s.Kind {
    case "foo":
        s.Spec = new(Foo)
    case "bar":
        s.Spec = new(Bar)
    default:
        panic("kind unknown")
    }
    return obj.Spec.Decode(s.Spec)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ryEuHyU-M2Z

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by implementing a custom `UnmarshalYAML` func. However, with the `v2` version of the API, you would basically do the same thing as you do now and just encapsulate it a bit better.

If you switch to using the `v3` API however, you get a better `UnmarshalYAML` that actually lets you work on the parsed YAML node *before* it is processed into a native Go type. Here's how that looks:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Spec struct {
    Kind string      `yaml:"kind"`
    Spec interface{} `yaml:"spec"`
}
type Foo struct {
    FooVal int `yaml:"fooVal"`
}
type Bar struct {
    BarVal int `yaml:"barVal"`
}

func (s *Spec) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    s.Kind = ""
    for i := 0; i < len(value.Content)/2; i += 2 {
        if value.Content[i].Kind == yaml.ScalarNode &&
            value.Content[i].Value == "kind" {
            if value.Content[i+1].Kind != yaml.ScalarNode {
                return errors.New("kind is not a scalar")
            }
            s.Kind = value.Content[i+1].Value
            break
        }
    }
    if s.Kind == "" {
        return errors.New("missing field `kind`")
    }
    switch s.Kind {
    case "foo":
        var foo Foo
        if err := value.Decode(&foo); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        s.Spec = foo
    case "bar":
        var bar Bar
        if err := value.Decode(&bar); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        s.Spec = bar
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown kind: " + s.Kind)
    }
    return nil
}

var input1 = []byte(`
kind: "foo"
spec:
  fooVal: 4
`)

var input2 = []byte(`
kind: "bar"
spec:
  barVal: 5
`)

func main() {
    var s1, s2 Spec
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input1, &s1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Type of spec from input1: %T\n", s1.Spec)
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input2, &s2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Type of spec from input2: %T\n", s2.Spec)
}
```

I suggest looking into the possibility of using YAML tags instead of your current structure to model this in your YAML; tags have been designed exactly for this purpose. Instead of the current YAML

```yaml
kind: "foo"
spec:
  fooVal: 4
```

you could write

```yaml
--- !foo
fooVal: 4
```

Now you don't need the describing structure with `kind` and `spec` anymore. Loading this would look a bit different as you'd need a wrapping root type you can define `UnmarshalYAML` on, but it may be feasible if this is just a part of a larger structure. You can access the tag `!foo` in the `yaml.Node`'s `Tag` field.