# Force unmarshal as interface{} instead of map[string]interface{}

Tags: go

I have the following YAML structure:

```
type Pipeline struct {
    Name string                  `yaml:"name"`
    Nodes map[string]NodeConfig  `yaml:"nodes"`
    Connections []NodeConnection `yaml:"connections"`
}

type NodeConfig struct {
    Type   string      `yaml:"type"`
    Config interface{} `yaml:"config"`
}
```

For each `NodeConfig`, depending on the value of `Type`, I need to detect the real type of `Config`.

```
switch nc.Type {
    case "request":
        return NewRequestNode(net, name, nc.Config.(RequestConfig))
    case "log":
        return NewLogNode(net, name)
    //...
}
```

This is the error I get from this:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not main.RequestConfig
```

I suspect it's because `Config` is getting automatically recognized as a `map[string]interface{}`, when I really want it to just be an `interface{}`. How can I do this?

Edit: [Minimal Example](https://goplay.tools/snippet/XCw0U33Dnow)

Comment: Go is statically typed, so if you declared `Config` as `interface{}` then it stays `interface{}`. Interface types can **hold** a value of any type that implements them however, this is called the interface's **dynamic** type (the "static" type is it's interface's type, i.e. `interface{}` in the above example). The expression `nc.Config.(RequestConfig)` is called a type assertion, a type assertion checks the dynamic type stored in the interface type. A type assertion succeeds only if the dynamic type matches the asserted type.

Comment: So if you yourself did not explicitly store a value of type `RequestConfig` inside `Config` then the type assertion will never ever succeed.

Comment: @mkopriva So what is the correct way to handle this? `Pipeline` is built directly from the unmarshal operation, not by me.

Comment: Generally what you can do is to have the type that can hold different types inspect the incoming data to discern the correct type, then based on that finding, initialize the correct type and resume the unmarshaling. https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3?#Unmarshaler

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709979/dynamically-parse-yaml-field-to-one-of-a-finite-set-of-structs-in-go/66713593#66713593

Comment: One thing you seem to be lacking in your understanding of unmarshal but is important to understand is that yaml.unmarshal has no way of knowing which type you would like it to use when decoding a node into an interface field. It will not, because it can not, magically divine the right type to fulfil the programmer's wishes.

Comment: @mkopriva Yeah I'll need to do some more reading because that just confused me way more lol. Parsing unknown data is the ONE concept in Go I've never been able to figure out. I've been using Go with great success for around 3 years now, and this is the one thing I've never been able to wrap my head around.

Comment: You would be better served if you provide a [mcve] (with stress on the *minimal*). Including an example of the raw yaml and an example of how you are invoking unmarshal.

Comment: @mkopriva done: https://goplay.tools/snippet/XCw0U33Dnow

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/ShepGrjDeqW or https://go.dev/play/p/0w-SxGpyeRi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the problem, it is getting automatically recognized as a `map[string]interface{}`, since you don't provide a custom UnmarshalYAML func the YAML package can only do that. But you actually don't want it as just `interface{}`, you need to identify which actual implementation you want for that.

### Solution using yaml.v3

I don't see how you can solve it without providing a custom `UnmarshalYAML` func to `NodeConfig` type. If that was JSON, I would read the `Config` as a `json.RawMessage`, then for each possible type I would unmarshal it into the desired type, and yaml.v3 equivalent seems to be a [yaml.Node type](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Node).

Using this, you can create a struct similar to `NodeConfig` which has the `Config` as `yaml.Node` and convert it to the concrete type based on the `Type` value, like this:

```golang
func (nc *NodeConfig) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var ncu struct {
        Type   string    `yaml:"type"`
        Config yaml.Node `yaml:"config"`
    }
    var err error

    // unmarshall into a NodeConfigUnmarshaler to detect correct type
    err = value.Decode(&ncu)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // now, detect the type and covert it accordingly
    nc.Type = ncu.Type
    switch ncu.Type {
    case "request":
        nc.Config = &RequestConfig{}
    case "log":
        nc.Config = &LogConfig{}
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unknown type %q", ncu.Type)
    }
    err = ncu.Config.Decode(nc.Config)

    return err
}
```

### Sample code

To test that, I created dummies `RequestConfig` and `LogConfig` and a sample:

```golang
type RequestConfig struct {
    Foo string `yaml:"foo"`
    Bar string `yaml:"bar"`
}

type LogConfig struct {
    Message string `yaml:"message"`
}

func main() {
    logSampleYAML := []byte(`
type: log
config:
    message: this is a log message
`)

    reqSampleYAML := []byte(`
type: request
config:
    foo: foo value
    bar: bar value
`)

    for i, val := range [][]byte{logSampleYAML, reqSampleYAML} {
        var nc NodeConfig
        err := yaml.Unmarshal(val, &nc)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("failed to parse sample %d: %v\n", i, err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("sample %d type %q (%T) = %+v\n", i, nc.Type, nc.Config, nc.Config)
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
sample 0 type "log" (*main.LogConfig) = &{Message:this is a log message}
sample 1 type "request" (*main.RequestConfig) = &{Foo:foo value Bar:bar value}
```

So, as you can see each instance of `NodeConfig` is instanciating the `Config` with the concrete type required, which means you can now use type assertion as `Confg.(*RequestConfig)` or `Config.(*LogConfig)` (or `switch`, of course).

You can play with that [solution in this Go Playground full sample](https://go.dev/play/p/QOMjoc7Owfy).

### Solution using yaml.v2

I have made a mistake and sent a solution with v2, but I recommend anyone to use the v3. If you can't, follow the v2 version...

The v2 does not have `yaml.Node`, but I found a very similar solution in the answer of [this issue](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/13#issuecomment-135407098) (I fixed a typo there):

```golang
type RawMessage struct {
    unmarshal func(interface{}) error
}

func (msg *RawMessage) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    msg.unmarshal = unmarshal
    return nil
}

func (msg *RawMessage) Unmarshal(v interface{}) error {
    return msg.unmarshal(v)
}
```

Which is an interesting trick, and with that you could bake your own `UnmarshalYAML` func by loading it into a temporary struct and then identifying each type you want and without needing to process the YAML twice:

```golang
func (nc *NodeConfig) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    var ncu struct {
        Type   string     `yaml:"type"`
        Config RawMessage `yaml:"config"`
    }
    var err error

    // unmarshall into a NodeConfigUnmarshaler to detect correct type
    err = unmarshal(&ncu)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // now, detect the type and covert it accordingly
    nc.Type = ncu.Type
    switch ncu.Type {
    case "request":
        cfg := &RequestConfig{}
        err = ncu.Config.Unmarshal(cfg)
        nc.Config = cfg
    case "log":
        cfg := &LogConfig{}
        err = ncu.Config.Unmarshal(cfg)
        nc.Config = cfg
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unknown type %q", ncu.Type)
    }

    return err
}
```

The sample code for v2 and v3 are identical.

You can play with that [solution in this Go Playground full sample](https://go.dev/play/p/MTn2UaQeHqM).

Comment: Note that you are using `yaml.v2` while `yaml.v3` has a different unmarshaler interface, so your solution, if OP is using `v3` (which is quite likely) will not exactly work for them, but it is the correct approach.

Comment: @mkopriva good point, I have missed that, very sorry... I'll update it to v3 shortly. Thanks

Comment: @mkopriva You already solved it from your comments before. If you post an answer I'll accept that, otherwise I'll take this one.

Comment: @chrispytoes I'm too lazy, feel free to accept this one, it's essentially the same thing just in an older version.

Comment: yaml.Node in v3 make it waaaaay simpler... Thanks for the point @mkopriva. Answer updated.